# My SASS extension setting files are ALL the same and the extension isn't working at all

Tags: css, node.js, sass, vscode-extensions

I've tried uninstalling the extension, checking env variables of the system and even reinstalling VS Code. Nothing seems to work. Literally all my `settings.json`files are all the same? This is what I see

```
{
    "explorer.confirmDelete": false
}
```

[Picture of the `settings.json` file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZIIH.png)

I dont know if maybe my system is corrupted or if I just haven't added the env variables which I dont think you need for SASS? (correct me if im wrong) Note that this did work before, and today i just didnt get the "watch sass" button. My take on this is that the extension isn't working because all my `settings.json` files are all the same. I also tried installing SASS through Node, but that didn't seem to work either. I don't know what else to do.

If anybody could help it'd be great!

Comment: A little more information on what you are trying to do would be great. And you should always get to your settings.json files through VS Code. If that is the extent of your settings file, thats a problem, 1st, try rebooting the computer

Comment: @Brad thanks for your response. I'm literally just trying to use it, but the "watch sass" button didn't show. Rebooting didn't seem to do anything, but I did install another SASS extension by Glenn Marks. I don't know if this is a development thing, or if it's just me.